# Failed to change one value in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

When using matrix in numpy, I want to change the value of one element in a matrix using the index, but the result I got is strange.

How can I change one value in indexing method?

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
mat1 = np.mat(arr)
mat1[1][0] = 3
print(arr)

[[1 2 3 4]
 [3 3 3 3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following change:

mat1[1][0] = 3 -> mat1[1,0] = 3